# BibLaTeX - How to cite with only year inside parenthesis

Tags: biblatex

BibLaTeX - How to cite with only year inside parenthesis?

(but only in some occasions - without changing how parencite works for the remaining citations)

I found some questions/answers but they either used natbib or were for different situations.

I thought about just trying to change the format of /citeyear but it doesn't create a link to the bibliography. Is it its normal behavior?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,dashed=false,backref=true,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\renewcommand\nameyeardelim{\addcomma\addspace}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{portuguese}{%
  url={Disponível em},
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Nunes,
    author = {Mister X},
    title = {Book Z english ensligh},
    year = {2013},
    location = {Lisboa, Portugal},
    note = {Dissertação para obtenção do Grau de Mestre em Engenharia Informática e de Computadores. Instituto Superior Técnico, Universidade de Lisboa},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Tal como Nunes no seu livro Z portuguese portuguese \citeyear{Nunes}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I'd like to get the following:

Tal como Nunes no seu livro Z portuguese portuguese (2013)

(with the normal link to the bibliography)

Comment: Why not simply `(\citeyear)`?

Comment: Because `\citeyear` doesn't create a link to the bibliography like `\parencite` or `\textcite`

Comment: As of time of writing, for me `\citeyear` does create a link to the bibioliography.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the starred version of `\cite` or `\parencite`. Those commands are defined for `authoryear`- and `authortitle`-like styles and simply omit the name.

```
\parencite*{sigfridsson} or \cite*{aksin}
```

If you are using the `natbib` compatibility mode, this function is overruled by `natbib`'s behaviour to temporary override the maxnames function and print all authors in the starred versions.
You will have to give the command a new name, the exact definition depends on the style, for `authoryear` it is

```
\DeclareCiteCommand*{\nparencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible to simply use `\citeyear` which, along with other `natbib` citation commands, creates a bibliography link.

See the [Overleaf `natbib` documentation](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_citation_styles) for a full list of commands